# UITapGestureRecognizer is not working on a floating imageview ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have 26 images added on a scroll view. I have given zigzag animation to this image while all the images are moving from right to left in the scroll view. I also implemented a UITapGestureRecognizer on each image so the image will act like a bubble breaker. it works fine when the images are not moving, But not when started animation.

Comment: How are you doing the animation? If you're using one of the animateWithDuration variants, did you add the option of,  UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction?

Comment: [UIView animateWithDuration:50.0f delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear|UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^
    {
        
        
        bgScroll.contentOffset = CGPointMake(4250, 0);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished)
     
     {
         
        // [self scrollAnimationEnded];
         [self performSelector:@selector(scrollAnimationEnded) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0];
     }];
Is this you mean???

Comment: This is my code to give the animation.

Answer (score 0):

Hit testing used for event routing operates on the model layer of your layers (and views) as opposed to the presentation layer.  Without any animation, the values (frame, center, bounds, ...) will match.  During an animation, the model layer's values are as they will appear at the end of the animation while the presentation layer's values correspond to what is currently on screen.

If you require hit testing to operate on the presentation layer, your views can override -pointInside: withEvent: to return the result of calling -containsPoint: on the presentation layer ([[self layer] presentationLayer]).

Comment: Thanks for answering Dex.. I am trying with it.

Comment: I know that this question must be answered a lot of times already, but it is really giving me a headache right now.

The touchesBegan: is not being called in my UIView. Before I added it in my app, I made a trial project first. In the trial project, everything worked perfectly.

Now, when I did the same thing in my existing app, the touchesBegan: method (as well as the touchesMoved:) is not called always,but it is called sometime. Can you explain to me why? I just don't really understand why it was never called.

Comment: this is my code:                                                     -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   
    NSLog(@"aaaa");
}
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    
    NSLog(@"bbbbb");
}
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"ccccc");
}